Abelian groups that can be extended with non abelian solvable groups
Let $H$ be a non-trivial finite abelian group. Is it true (in some cases) that there exist a non-abelian solvable group $G$ and a normal abelian subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that  $G/K$ isomorphic to $H$? Can we classify all the groups $H$ that have this property?

I mean that if we know the group H, can we ensure that there exists a non abelian solvable group G with the previous property?

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Yes, just take the wreath product $C_2 \wr H$.

The semidirect product $G=H\ltimes H$ of a finite abelian group $H$ by itself is clearly solvable, because $H$ is solvable. If we can take a nontrivial semidirect product, then $G$ is also nonabelian, see here:
Which groups are a non-trivial semidirect product of abelian groups?
Hence, with the normal subgroup $K=H$, we obtain that $G/K\cong H$, i.e., the sequence
$$
1\rightarrow H \rightarrow G \rightarrow K \rightarrow 1 
$$
is exact.
Edit: In case that every homomorphism $H\rightarrow {\rm Aut}(H)$ is trivial, e.g., for $H=C_p$, we need the existence of a non-split extension. However, it is known that
$$
H^2(C_p,C_p)\cong \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z,
$$
so there are $p-1$ inequivalent non-split extensions of $C_p$ by $C_p$.

Perhaps I'm just being obtuse, but wouldn't this construction require existence of a non-trivial hom of $H$ to its automorphism group? So $H\approx \mathbb Z/p$ wouldn't allow this construction?

If we put a condition that K mus not be isomorphic to H, then can we build such a group G?

@paulgarrett You are right, this is really an issue.

@RozinaAli I think, yes, we find some metabelian (so nonabelian, $2$-step solvable) group $G$, with two non-isomorphic finite abelian groups $H$ and $K$.

Thanks for your clear answer, now, how can we build such a meta abelian group G? Is it existed for every H?

By showing that the second cohomology $H^2(K,H)$ is non-trivial for some finite abelian group $K$, different from our given $H$. Then there is such a non-split extension. Perhaps one can solve this differently, though.

It's maybe easier to just choose an Abelian $K$ on which some element of prime order in $H$ will act non trivially. For example if $H$ is even order, form the semi direct product $K\rtimes H$ where the image of $H$ in $Aut(K)$ has order 2 (could be inversion).

The wreath product $X \wr H$ for any nontrivial abelian group $X$ does the job.
